# Linker is unable to locate curl_global_init

Tags: linux, curl, hyperlink, undefined

I am compiling a C++ application on Ubuntu 18.04.
The linker is unable to pickup the required functions from the library or it is not locating the right library

I have `libcurl.so` located at `/usr/local/lib`

`nm -D` lists all the functions I need with `T prefix`. Yet when I compile as follows

```sh
g++ -std=c++17  -lcurl  tz.o main.o
```

I get

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: tz.o: in function 'date::curl_global()':
tz.cpp:(.text+0x9aef): undefined reference to 'curl_global_init'
```

I tried installing `openssl-dev`. No joy. So I uninstalled it.

Comment: try `g++ -std=c++17 tz.o main.o -lcurl` instead... g++ is shit in some ways, like argument ordering. (all i did was to make -lcurl the last argument instead of argument #3)

Comment: if you want to use httpS:// URLs, you're going to need openssl-dev tho (or 1 of the [many alternatives](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-compared.html), like wolfssl-dev)

Comment: Please provide it as an answer that I may accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
g++ -std=c++17 tz.o main.o -lcurl
```

instead... g++ is shit in some ways, like argument ordering. (all i did was to make -lcurl the last argument instead of argument #3)